# Dependent dropdown list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table. I have three columns, `1-`**Company**, `2-`**Product**, `3-`**Area**. The data is unordered and duplicate values are also there.

[image: Excel sheet]

Then below the table, I am doing working... I can use cell validation, but it does not give what I want. I also don't want to order/arrange the data. I want the below results without rearranging or touching the table.

When I cell `C13`, it should show only the unique Company.

Then, the dropdown list of the Product in the cell `C14` should filter based on the Company.

After that when I click in the cell `C15`, it should give a filtered dropdown list of Area based on the Company and Product.

In my example, the cell `C15` dropdown list should show only `123` and `456`.

Comment: If you were to re-order the data it would be very easy to use an indirect drop down, however, if you don't want to do this, how about creating a pivot of the data, then using the pivot to drive the indirect dropdowns?

Comment: I did not understand. I think it will not work. I tried to do this but unsuccessful... in pivot we can have only one as rows.. that may solve company duplicate values but what about dependent product and dependent area...

Comment: Can you give any suggestion to do this through power query pivot...

Comment: there are 99% chances that area code will always be different. So i have directly input the area in ‘c15’ and applied index match formula on ‘c14’ & ‘c13’ .  But if someday area code is duplicated then what???